# Factory Design Pattern Explanation

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

In most factory's pattern explanation topics, we are told that factories are needed to refuse using `new` for for instantiating objects. Instead it we need to instantiate factories with `new`, that do `new` for concrete objects for us.

But why? In that case we just have excess middle class.
[For example here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#PHP)

In my code I use this way. Is it factory? Is it right way?

```
    <?php

abstract class CarAbstract
{

    abstract public function makeSignal();

    public static function factory($type)
    {
        switch($type) {
            'automobile':
                return new AutoCar();
                break;
            'truck':
                return new TruckCar();
                break;
        }
    }
}

class AutoCar extends CarAbstract {

    public function makeSignal()
    {
        return 'beep-beep';
    }
}

class TruckCar extends CarAbstract {

    public function makeSignal()
    {
        return 'faa-faa';
    }
}

$auto = CarAbstract::factory('automobile');
$truck = CarAbstract::factory('truck');

$auto->makeSignal(); // beep-beep
$truck->makeSignal(); // faa-faa
```

P.S.
Excuse me for my english

Comment: Factory design is mainly for Testability (Unit test)

Comment: Please post your actual code here, not a link to your code.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia page you link to explains why:

> The Factory Method design pattern solves problems like:
>
> How can an object be created so that subclasses can redefine which class to instantiate?
>
> How can a class defer instantiation to subclasses?

Personally the most useful situation I have found in PHP for factories is when implementing libraries.  This is a matter of opinion, but I find factories to usually be excessive inside the core of my PHP applications.  But when writing a library to be used by multiple applications it allows a lot more flexibility in providing specific implementations.

The example you provide will work but is not the best way to implement the pattern.  It's usually better to make a concrete factory class which you instantiate.  Or even better an interface which you then implement.  Then it's more useful and easier to unit test.

Answer (score 0):

The factory pattern is useful when the actual type of the object is determined dynamically.

```
$carType = $_POST['type'];
$cat = CarAbstract::factory($carType);
```

This allows you to implement the `switch` statement once in the base class, rather than having to code it in all the applications that use these classes. And if you add more subclasses, you just update that one `switch` statement, rather than having to find all the callers.

Comment: Yes. Now I do it like this